# SBT fails to resolve dependency for plugin with no IVY (only POM)

Tags: scala, proxy, sbt, repository

I work behind a corporate proxy, hence I'm using [proxy repositories](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html). It works fine, but only for the dependencies defined in `build.sbt`. For the dependencies required by plugins (declared with `addSbtPlugin`) the proxy repositories work only if the dependency has an `ivy.xml`. If it's defined with just `*.pom` files, it cannot be resolved, e.g. a transitive dependency for the `com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly` plugin:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1 {compile=
[default(compile)]}::
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.typesafe.com
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.scala-sbt.org
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/bundles/scalactic_2.12.jar: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.typesafe.com
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.scalactic:scalactic_2.12:3.0.1
[warn]            +- com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.6 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\<path to the project>\project\assembly.sbt#L1-2)
```

SBT creates the `org.scalactic` directory in `.ivy2/cache` and adds two files:

```
.ivy2/cache
        |___org.scalactic
                   |___scalactic_2.12
                                |___ivy-3.0.1.xml.original
                                |___ivydata-3.0.1.properties
```

SBT probably generates that files, as in the repository there are only the following:

```
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-javadoc.jar           10-Nov-2016 00:50  1.82 MB
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-javadoc.jar.asc->         -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-javadoc.jar.asc.md5->     -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-javadoc.jar.asc.sha1->    -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-javadoc.jar.md5       10-Nov-2016 00:50  32 bytes
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-javadoc.jar.sha1      10-Nov-2016 00:50  40 bytes
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-sources.jar           10-Nov-2016 00:50  196.37 KB
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-sources.jar.asc->         -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-sources.jar.asc.md5->     -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-sources.jar.asc.sha1->    -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-sources.jar.md5       10-Nov-2016 00:50  32 bytes
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1-sources.jar.sha1      10-Nov-2016 00:50  40 bytes
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.jar                   10-Nov-2016 00:50  689.03 KB
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.jar.asc->                 -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.jar.asc.md5->             -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.jar.asc.sha1->            -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.jar.md5               10-Nov-2016 00:50  32 bytes
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.jar.sha1              10-Nov-2016 00:50  40 bytes
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom                   10-Nov-2016 00:50  2.18 KB
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom.asc->                 -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom.asc.md5->             -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom.asc.sha1->            -    -
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom.md5               10-Nov-2016 00:50  32 bytes
scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom.sha1              10-Nov-2016 00:50  40 bytes
```

We can see that SBT reads the `*.pom` files, but then does something strange:

(Note: `maven-central` is the name given to a pattern in `repositories` file)

```
tried http://<path to repository>/artifactory/maven-central/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom
maven-central: found md file for org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1
    => http://<path to repository>/artifactory/maven-central/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom (3.0.1)
downloading http://<path to repository>/artifactory/maven-central/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom ...
maven-central: downloading http://<path to repository>/artifactory/maven-central/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom
maven-central: downloading http://<path to repository>/artifactory/maven-central/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom.sha1
sha1 OK for http://<path to repository>/artifactory/maven-central/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.pom
[SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1!scalactic_2.12.pom(pom.original) (330ms)
    tried https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/bundles/scalactic_2.12.jar
problem occurred while resolving dependency: org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1 {compile=[default(compile)]} with maven-central: java.lang.RuntimeException: typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/bundles/scalactic_2.12.jar: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.typesafe.com
```

finally failing with:

```
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/bundles/scalactic_2.12.jar: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.typesafe.com
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

without being able to start (`ignore` doesn't help).

I have a workaround:

- declare the failed dependency in the `build.sbt`
- add some dummy code that uses the dependency
- call `sbt compile`

This way the dependency is somehow resolved and stored to `.ivy2/cache`:

```
[info] downloading http://<path to repository>/artifactory/maven-central/org/scalactic/scalactic_2.12/3.0.1/scalactic_2.12-3.0.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalactic#scalactic_2.12;3.0.1!scalactic_2.12.jar(bundle) (1138ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

Then I remove the dummy code and it works based on the cached dependency. I don't like this "solution" for obvious reasons.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could answer my questions:

1. Why is the same dependency failing to resolve for the plugin, but is resolved at compile?
2. Is there a way to tell SBT to resolve the dependency without looking for `ivy.xml` (the same way it does it at compile)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use it in build via enabling it explicitly - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html

Comment: Added `enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)` to `build.sbt`. Same result.

Comment: Don't know if this works with your proxy, but I always add the following line to plugins.sbt: resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugin-releases",url("https://dl.bintray.com/content/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)